# Ansible AWX - Deploy multiple hosts with different credentials with one playbook in one AWX template

Tags: ansible

Environment are 3 hosts. Hosts A; B and C
Host A runs Ansible with AWX within a Docker container.
My Task is, to fetch backup files from host B, and transfer them to server C.
In fact, this are two task.
Hosts B and C have different Credentials.
I know how to gather this both task in one playbook, but how can I add the second credential to the C server to establish the copy task in an AWX template?

Playbook example:

````
- hosts: B
  tasks:
  - name: Fetch backup data from remote host B to my_path
    fetch:
      src: /origin_path/backup_file.tar.gz
      dest: /my_path/backup_file.tar.gz

- hosts: C
  tasks:
  - name: Copy backup data from my_path to remote host C
    tasks:
      copy:
      src: /my_path/backup_file.tar.gz
      dest: /remote_path/backup_file.tar.gz
```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can look into using inventory variables to set the credentials for your hosts (via host vars or group vars).

1. Encrypt your passwords using Ansible Vault (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#choosing-between-a-single-password-and-multiple-passwords)
2. Set the ansible_user and ansible_password host variables in your inventory(note the ansible_password is the value encrypted using ansible-vault)
3. create a Vault credential in AWX which will store the key used to encrypt your password
4. add the vault credential to your playbook Template in AWX. This will ensure that the password is decrypted when the playbook is run.

you can use inventory variables to handle multiple domain credentials for servers

Answer (score 1):

For this type of scenario I have created separate playbooks for each host, created a template for each playbook and then used a workflow template to run the two playbooks in sequence.

I'd like a better solution, which would be to allow multiple credentials as you describe.